# Alternative to deprecated AudioSessionGetProperty, for iOS 7

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I am using AudioSessionGetProperty to check 'audioIsAlreadyPlaying'.
Xcode says:  *'AudioSessionGetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0*

Please could someone tell me what I should use instead, to get the **audioIsAlreadyPlaying** property.

```
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,
                        &propertySize,
                        &audioIsAlreadyPlaying);
return audioIsAlreadyPlaying;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Trying using the `AVAudioSession`'s [`otherAudioPlaying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/otherAudioPlaying) property on iOS 6.0 or higher.

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying]`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, and the code is tidier than the deprecated code, nice. Thanks Benoit!

Comment: To save some of you the lookup, this requires: #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: hi can you tell how to set the property for "kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory"?

Answer (score 1):

The AVAudioSession class replaces deprecated AudioSession APIs. For what you're doing, see the [otherAudioPlaying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/otherAudioPlaying) property.

Comment: Thanks Rickster! I gave Benoit the green tick because he provided the line of code, and I don't know who posted first. Thanks a lot for your response.