# Get device output volume for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, avaudiosession

I am working on iOS library for playing audio ads, I want to check if the device output volume is zero ( silent or muted) every time before requesting the ad.

I have used the following codeAny  to check the output volume for the device

```
+(BOOL)isDeviceMuted
{
    Float32 val = -1.0;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(val);
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, &propertySize, &val);

    NSLog(@"value of volume: %f",val);
    if (val <= 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    } 
}
```

This code works perfect until now but the problem that AudioSessionGetProperty is deprecated on iOS 7 and I want to replace this code with new one that are not deprecated ( minimum iOS SDK is 6 )

I have tried the following

```
val = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
```

but the problem with outputVolume that it needs audio session to be active in order to track changes on it.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

and we can't do that inside library since it will affect user application (sharedInstance)

Any ideas !!

Comment: This [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945931/alternative-to-deprecated-audiosessiongetproperty-for-ios-7][1] may give you solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945931/alternative-to-deprecated-audiosessiongetproperty-for-ios-7

Comment: Keep using old code. Deprecated does not mean broken or illegal.

Comment: deprecated means that it will be invalid in some iOS release

Answer (score 0):

use otherAudioPlaying property to determine whether another app is playing audio

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying]
```

Comment: I am asking about device volume not if other audio is playing

Comment: I see,  as you mentioned "... we can't do that inside library since it will affect user application", in this case you know if there is no other audio playing you call setActive and get output volume from AVAudioSession's sharedInstance, is it clear ?

Comment: But if the publisher is setting the audio session to NO, then when requesting the ad, audio session will be be set to YES and this will override publisher value ... I cant play with any value that is shared !!!!