# Deprecated in iOS7: AudioSessionSetProperty

Tags: ios, audio

How can I replace the following lines of code (Xcode complains `AudioSessionSetProperty`  is deprecated as of iOS 7):

```
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945931/alternative-to-deprecated-audiosessiongetproperty-for-ios-7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to do something like

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession; // get your audio session somehow

BOOL success = [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"error doing outputaudioportoverride - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

[This API is available](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/overrideOutputAudioPort%3aerror%3a) in iOS 6 & newer iOS versions.